# how to convert fstring variable to 2 decimal places in python?

Tags: python

How do I print:

`print(f"\nTotal amount inserted: ${total_money}")`

So that total money will display to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the number of decimal places with the `N` in `{num:.Nf}`.
For example:

```py
>>> print(f'{2:.2f}')
2.00
```